# Tortoise SVN 1.12.0 stops working in Win 10 x64

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I have updated TortoiseSVN from 1.11.1 to 1.12.0 in a Windows 10 x64.

I'm able to perform any SVN operation (checkout, commit, update...) but Tortoise crashes when I try "Repo-browser" in a URL that contains externals items. It shows a message "Tortoise x64 stopped working..."

I've done a clean installation (removing and reinstalling Tortoise) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: error logs? System logs? Error message?

Comment: Where are the logs? Error message is a pop-up window saying "Tortoise stopped working", then it crashes

Comment: I have the same thing

Answer (score 4):

This issue appears also in my computer and in my colleagues.
No evidence of the cause was found. The debugOutputString was enabled and DebugView was used to gather logs. As Shown here: [How To Debug SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614894/how-to-debug-something-in-tortoisesvn)
But there was nothing unusual there.

A workaround that restores repo browser is to uninstall the 1.12.0 and install TortoiseSVN-1.10.3.28489-x64-svn-1.10.4. It might not be that easy if there is a feature of 1.12 that is required, but it works.